# How to Get Index of Specific UIViewController in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So, switching programatically from one tab in a `UITabBarController` to another is easy enough...

`self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`

...but hard-coding the tab index each time seems pretty inelegant. It would cause problems if the tabs were re-ordered, for example.

Is there a way to retrieve the [first] index of a specific `UIViewController`, so that the code could be something more like the following?

```
if let destinationIndex = self.tabBarController?.index(of: ExampleViewController) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = destinationIndex
}
```

Comment: In what instance would the tab indexes be reordered?

Comment: A design change by the developer, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use the `firstIndex(where:)` method.

```
if let destinationIndex = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(where: { $0 is ExampleViewController }) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = destinationIndex
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I hadn't thought to do the operation on the viewControllers property, rather than on the tabBarController itself. That explains why I couldn't find it.

Comment: Any idea how to make it work if the VC is embedded in a UINavigationController? I know it would use .viewControllers.first is SuggestionsViewController, but not sure how to cast the $0 parameter to UINavigationController so that check can be made.

Comment: I worked it out:
```if let destinationIndex = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.firstIndex(where: {
            let navController = $0 as? UINavigationController
            return navController?.viewControllers.first is ExampleViewController
        }) {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = destinationIndex
        }```

Answer (score 0):

For those to whom it applies, this is the answer from @[Craig Siemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385017/craig-siemens), adapted for when the target VC is embedded in a navigation controller:

```
if let destinationIndex = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.firstIndex(where: {
    let navController = $0 as? UINavigationController
    return navController?.viewControllers.first is ExampleViewController
}) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = destinationIndex
}
```